# Getting Unauthorized when trying to run Echo-Connector-Bot

Tags: python, botframework

I would like to set up a Microsoft Teams bot in Python.

Trying to run [this](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-python/tree/master/samples/Echo-Connector-Bot) sample, and getting the following error message:

```
botbuilder.schema._models_py3.ErrorResponseException: Operation returned an invalid status code 'Unauthorized'
```

I also tried following a few other guides, such as [this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/get-started/get-started-nodejs-app-studio), and got it working.

Searched for similar questions here on SO, but couldn't find anything relevant either.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You say you got it working. What is your question?

Comment: @KyleDelaney I got the NodeJS sample working, not the Python one.

Comment: Did you configure your bot with a Microsoft app ID and password?

Comment: @KyleDelaney Yes, I've set up a bot in the App Studio, got the app ID and password, and updated lines 12 and 13 in the sample code accordingly. I'm using the same ID and password with the Node.JS sample.

Comment: Does it work in other channels like Web Chat or do you get the same error?

Comment: I'm able to test in Web Chat and get expected response (bot echoed my message).

Comment: Are you running the bot locally and using a tunneling service for your endpoint in Azure?

Comment: Yes, I'm using ngrok.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue. Would you like to email me privately in order to share your code?

Comment: Sure, will mail you.